OpenAPI TypeScript generator can't exclude files
I have a Next.js React TypeScript app. I want to make use of the OpenAPI Generator based on my api-docs.yaml file. After I successfuly generated my types, I am importing them where I need in my project. Even if all of the generated files have those 2 lines at the top of the file:
**/* tslint:disable */**
**/* eslint-disable */**

I am still not able to exclude those from my Next build process where the type checking is happening. I simply don't want those generated files to be typed checked by TypeScript, especially when I run the next build command.
Project structure:
api/
src/
tsconfig.json

tsconfig.json;
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": false,
    "types": ["jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "target": "ES2022",
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      // "@features/*": ["./src/features/*"],
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@/api/*": ["api/*"],
      "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
    },
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/types/tailwind-datepicker-react.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "api/**/*"
  ]
}

.eslintignore:
api/**/*

.eslintrc.json:
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "ignorePatterns":  ["api/**/*.ts"]
}

